# Porting Keras older version models to latest version

Tags: keras, porting, pre-trained-model

I've a pretrained model in Keras-0.3.3. It is saved as json_file and weights file. If I try to load it in latest keras, it fails. How can I port the model to latest keras version?

PS: The model I'm referring to is in this [github page](https://gist.github.com/albertomontesg/d8b21a179c1e6cca0480ebdf292c34d2)

**Edit 1**: Adding code and error

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
from keras import backend
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json

model_path = Path('../Data/C3D/sports_1M.json')
weights_path = Path('../Data/C3D/sports1M_weights.h5')
c3d_model = model_from_json(open(model_path.as_posix(), 'r').read())
print(c3d_model.summary())
```

Error is like below

```
ValueError: Improper config format: {'name': 'Sequential', 'layers': [{'input_shape': [3, 16, 112, 112], 'activation': 'relu' ...
```

Comment: What is the latest version you're on?

Comment: I'm using Keras-2.3.1

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Added in question

Comment: Read yourself the JSON file and build the model by hand. I think it will not be easy (or trustable) to use any attempt of portability.

Comment: I did that. But then when loading weights, I was getting some error like
"Can't load weights of 0 layers into model of 15 layers".

Comment: I'm amazed these libraries don't provide porting script. If somebody is using this in production environment, what do they do in such scenarios?

Comment: Maybe you should try to install (is it possible) some Keras 1.0.0, open and resave the model. Then try keras 2.... a weird attempt.

Comment: Ha ha! Thanks. That's a ... as you put it, weird attempt. Will try that sometime.